# Source code migration from one VSTS repository to another VSTS repository

Tags: azure-devops, code-migration

We have two VSTS repositories assuming **abc**.visualstudio.com & **xyz**.visualstudio.com and we need to migrate the source code along with the history into **final**.visualstudio.com.

For now we managed to migrate the work items by exporting from abc & xyz into final repositories but couldn't find a way to migrate the source code along with the history.

Pl. let me know is there a way we can migrate multiple repositories into single repository.

Appreciate your time and help in advance.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC repositories?

Comment: Can you explain how you "export from abc & xyz into final repositories"? And What's you Version Control System (Git or TFVC)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git repository it is possible and if you are TFVC it is not possible to migrate.

Check the below link for more information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository?view=vsts

Comment: There are tools for TFVC that allow history migration.

Comment: @sheethal, unfortunately, all of my repositories are in TFVC and even in my target repository also we wanted to keep the TFCS repos. Pl. share if anybody have any thoughts

Comment: @DanielMann what are the tools? Are they for TFS only?